# Generate images of different size in GAN

Tags: tensorflow

I have a GAN network which output a 32x32 images and it's working fine.
I'm trying to output a 128x48 images but no matter how I change the filter size and stride, it always output an NxN images. 
Can somebody tell me how to output an NxM images. What values need to be moditified. 
I'm using Tensorflow/Python and my deconv layer uses  `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d_transpose`
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well how about this? You generate image of size 128*128 using conv2d_transpose. It is possible you know, upscaling and stuff. Then, you resize the image using opencv, or maybe PIL to 128*48. Easy!